# "\item[text]" text of a description list going off of page

Tags: line-breaking, description

I am trying to make a description list in which an item has quite a long name and the text goes off of the page to the right instead of wrapping to the next line.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item[The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog] Lorem me some ipsum yo
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have tried putting `\\`, `\hfill`, `\newline`, `\linebreak`, and `\break` inside the square brackets between the words, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optional argument of `\item[]` inside a `description` list is set in a box in **bold**. This box doesn't care for any of `\\`, `\hfill`, `\newline`, `linebreak` or `\break`, hence the output.

This may be a special case of your item, so you may want to handle it in that way:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item[The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog]
      Lorem me some ipsum yo

    \item\hspace*{-\labelsep}{\bfseries The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}\hspace*{\labelsep}
      Lorem me some ipsum yo

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to set the regular label as part of the item but compensating for the `\labelsep` gap. The above is the default output when using the `style=sameline` option with [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=sameline]
    \item[The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog]
      Lorem me some ipsum yo
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

---

You could also manipulate the paragraph shape, depending on the type out output you're interested in:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
    \item[The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog]
      Lorem me some ipsum yo

    \item \parshape 4 \dimexpr\leftmargin-\labelsep\relax \dimexpr\linewidth-\leftmargin+\labelsep\relax
                      0pt \linewidth
                      0pt \linewidth
                      \leftmargin \dimexpr\linewidth-\leftmargin\relax%
      {\bfseries The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog}\hspace*{\labelsep}
      Lorem me some ipsum yo Lorem me some ipsum yo Lorem me some ipsum yo Lorem me some ipsum yo Lorem me some ipsum yo

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly; thank you for your timely response.